# AAA authentication error in DataPower

Tags: authentication, authorization, saml, ibm-datapower, aaa-security-protocol

I have create AAA policy and validating SAML attribute in AAA authentication. 
I am getting error as 'AAA Authentication Failure'
I am not getting detailed error message why I am getting the AAA error.

Any help?

Comment: What is the logging type selected in DataPower control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your log level.

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select "Trouble Shooting"
3. Select Log Level
4. Set Level as "Debug"
5. Trigger transaction.
6. You can see all the transaction even AAA error

Answer (score 0):

Enable the multistep probes. You can get a better view on what exactly is happening within the service.